# Protocol Buffer with CMakeLists

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

I have a project which has `src`, `include` and some older folders under its parent dictory. I created a folder called `proto`, which has my `VisionData.proto` in it. I want to generate the expected output files, however it doesn't work. I looked at the official site of [it](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindProtobuf.html)  and did whatever they wrote there, but still no luck. Here is my CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(uwsim_imgproc)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set_source_files_properties(${PROTO_SRC} ${PROTO_HEADER} PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  image_transport
)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)


catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include
LIBRARIES uwsim_imgproc filters
CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge roscpp sensor_msgs std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)


set(PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS} PARENT_SCOPE)
set(PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES} PARENT_SCOPE)
set(PROTO_SRC ${PROTO_SRC} PARENT_SCOPE)
set(PROTO_HEADER ${PROTO_HEADER} PARENT_SCOPE)


PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS VisionData.proto)


include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
  ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  include
)

link_directories( 
  ${OpenCV_LINK_DIRS}
)

add_library(filters
        src/Obstacle.cpp
            src/HorizonDetector.cpp
            src/GenericTools.cpp
        src/Kalman.cpp
        src/HungarianAlg.cpp
        src/Ctracker.cpp
)

add_executable(cameraSubscriber src/main.cpp)
add_executable(VisionData VisionData.cc ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})

add_dependencies(cameraSubscriber ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

target_link_libraries(VisionData 
${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES}
)

target_link_libraries(filters
   ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
)

target_link_libraries(cameraSubscriber
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
   filters
 )
```

And the error message I get is:

```
CMake Error at uwsim_imgproc/CMakeLists.txt:60 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    VisionData.cc

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

Fixed the issue with the error, however, my CMakeLists does not generate any .h or .cc file which should have been generated.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(uwsim_imgproc)
include(FindProtobuf)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set_source_files_properties(${PROTO_SRC} ${PROTO_HEADER} PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  image_transport
)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)


catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include
LIBRARIES uwsim_imgproc filters
CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge roscpp sensor_msgs std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)


set(PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS} PARENT_SCOPE)
set(PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES} PARENT_SCOPE)
set(PROTO_SRC ${PROTO_SRC} PARENT_SCOPE)
set(PROTO_HEADER ${PROTO_HEADER} PARENT_SCOPE)


PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS proto/VisionData.proto)


include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
  ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  include
)

link_directories( 
  ${OpenCV_LINK_DIRS}
)

add_library(filters
        src/Obstacle.cpp
            src/HorizonDetector.cpp
            src/GenericTools.cpp
        src/Kalman.cpp
        src/HungarianAlg.cpp
        src/Ctracker.cpp
)

add_executable(cameraSubscriber src/main.cpp ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})

add_dependencies(cameraSubscriber ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

target_link_libraries(cameraSubscriber 
${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES}
)

target_link_libraries(filters
   ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
)

target_link_libraries(cameraSubscriber
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
   filters
 )
```

Comment: For the patience shown in coming to the bottom of this, +1. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the source files generated by `protobuf_generate_cpp()` ends up in `PROTO_SRCS`.

1. This file will likely be generated in `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` (since it's CMake policy not to generate files in the source directory).
2. This file probably follows some internal naming scheme you don't have to know about.

So your line...

```
add_executable(VisionData VisionData.cc ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})
```

...should probably not have `VisionData.cc` in it.

Comment: The example given in the website has .cc file in that line, so I put it there. Now that I removed it, I got `make[2]: *** No rule to make target uwsim_imgproc/VisionData.proto', needed by uwsim_imgproc/VisionData.pb.cc'.  Stop.`

Comment: @frageDE: The module has an example `foo.proto`, and the `add_executable()` line lists `bar.cc`. ;-) Regarding the new error, does `uwsim_imgproc/VIsionData.proto` exist in `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`?

Comment: .proto file is in a folder called proto, and that folder is on the same level with CMakeLists.txt file. Should I specify the path in CMakeLists.xtxt? Like `/proto/VisionData.proto`?

Comment: @frageDE: Yes, you need to specify source file paths relative to your SOURCE_DIR, like you did in `add_libary()`. That would be `proto/VisionData.proto`, no leading slash.

Comment: I did so, now it gives another error. I don't know if this error is related to the topic, but nevertheless I am sharing it.

`Linking CXX executable /uwsim_imgproc/VisionData
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function _start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [uwsim_ws/devel/lib/uwsim_imgproc/VisionData] Error 1
make[1]: *** [uwsim_imgproc/CMakeFiles/VisionData.dir/all] Error 2`

Comment: @frageDE: Well, where **is** your `main()` function defined? You need one in the sources listed for `add_executable()`...

Comment: The thing is, this project works without any problem itself. When I include the proto file and just try to generate its expected output files, it doesn't compile. So there is nothing wrong with my main() or whatsoever.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90008/discussion-between-devsolar-and-fragede).

Comment: I tried everything but couldn't get it to generate .cc and .h files. I get no error by now, but I do not have any generated cpp files.

Comment: @frageDE: Sorry I abandoned the chat. I don't know what your source is doing. I don't even know what "Protobuf" is about. I don't know if you need an executable. The `protobuf_generate_cpp()` call takes a `*.proto` input, generates sources and headers, and returns their names as the lists `PROTO_SRCS` and `PROTO_HDRS`. I assume you will want to use those generated sources somewhere; whether that's in an executable, or some library, I don't know. If you drop the `add_executable()` line, you will **not** be using the sources for anything; that doesn't sound useful to me, but it's your project.

Comment: I just wanted to get two files (.h and .cc) out of .proto file and I am unable to do this. With makefile it is very easy to generate these, but with CMakeLists it is not for some reason.

My CMakeLists.txt does not generate any .h or .cc file.

Comment: @frageDE: How do you figure? Add `message( "${PROTO_SRCS}" )` after `protobuf_generate_cpp()`. You should see something along the lines of `[...]/VisionData.pb.cc`. That's your generated source.

Comment: @frageDE: Ah... of course, if you don't *use* those sources anywhere (like, not using `${PROTO_SRCS}` in any `add_library()` / `add_executable()`), then nothing *depends* on them, and they won't get generated...

Comment: Now I am able to see the generated files yes, do you know how to specify their location though? I do not want them to be generated under the parent directory. I created a special folder called src-gen, and I want those to be there.  And no, putting this `set(PROTO_SRC ${PROTO_SRC} PARENT_SCOPE/src-gen)
set(PROTO_HEADER ${PROTO_HEADER} PARENT_SCOPE/src-gen)` does not help :)

Comment: @frageDE: The `FindProtobuf.cmake` module generates the files in `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}`. While I understand the desire to maintain a "clean" binary directory, at this point I would say "don't bother", because you would pay for it with a less "clean" `CMakeLists.txt` setup (`add_subdirectory()`), and I don't feel it's worth that. Anyway, that would be a whole new question; I think we've ping-ponged on this one long enough. ;-)